# Spring Boot 2 with AngularJS MIME type and 401 errors

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have recently upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0 and after a plethora of updates I excitedly went to run my app only to be hit with a series of confusing errors.

The browser reports

> Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

error against our css files however the server logs show:

```
2018-06-06 16:34:27.993 DEBUG 11316 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Wed Jun 06 16:34:27 BST 2018, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Unauthorized, path=/css/main.css}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3b4f1eb]
2018-06-06 16:34:27.993 DEBUG 11316 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-06-06 16:34:27.993 DEBUG 11316 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

I've tried setting the MIME type on the script / link tags in the `index.html` which removes the errors on the files but gives the ever so helpful error

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

It seems as if Spring can't read from the static folder, and I've tried just about every solution I can find around this.

Comment: In your angular app are you "injecting" properly the dependencies?

Comment: Yes all was working find prior to upgrade on spring boot front end remained the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into similar problems setting this in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will resolve:

```
.requestMatchers( PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
                .permitAll()
```